# How do I properly get responses for the jQuery post function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json, express

I'm new in js and I'm having problems with my node application.
I have a function like this in the client side:

```
$('form#formNewCustomer').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    $.post(
        $form.attr("action"),
        $form.serialize(),
        function (data) { alert("first success") },
        "json"
    ).done(function () {
        alert("second success");
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("error");
    }).always(function () {
        alert("finished");
    });
});
```

And a function like this in the server side:

```
app.post('/customer',
[
    check('email', "Invalid E-mail.").isEmail().normalizeEmail().optional({ checkFalsy: true }),
    check('name', "Empty name").trim().isLength({ min: 2 }).escape(),
],
(req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        console.log(errors)
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() })
    } else {
        collection.insertOne(req.body)
            .then(result => {
                //do something
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error))
    }
})
```

The problem is, it always alerts the 'fail' function, what can I do to return properly and to alert the 'check' messages ('invalid e-mail' for example)?

Comment: If it's alerting fail, check your browser console to see what the error is.

Comment: a 422 status is a failure when using jquery's ajax methods and will enter the error handler. Look to the error handler's parameters for more information.